# How to use InAppPurchase in an enterprise application?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am developing an application in which I am using InAppPurchase feature. I don't want to submit my application to Appstore and use this application as an enterprise application. My question is that without submitting the app to AppStore, how to make InApp Purchasing work?

Comment: Why would you need to purchase anything if the app was written for your own company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty certain you can't have Apple process your IAP without your application being uploaded to the AppStore.

Comment: you can distribute enterprise apps trough the app store

Comment: "I don't want to submit my application to Appstore" I think he means internal distribution, but I don't know, all I'm saying is I don't think he can do IAPs without the app being hosted by Apple

Comment: How can i distribute enterprice app through appstore

Comment: You can't.  It is for in-house.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/ read more of how to distribute your enterprise apps here